# can haarCascades be used to get object size?

Tags: opencv, image-processing, opencv3.0, haar-classifier

i'm new to image processing . i want detect a set of objects in the image and compare the sizes . can this be possible using haarCascades

Comment: Have you implemented anything yet? What language are you using?

Answer (score 2):

Very possible, just return the size of a bounding box around your detected object, you can do this in various ways like getting the width and height of a rectangle you draw around your object. Another simple way is to use `size`.

In C++ it can look like this:

```
//-- Detect faces
  face_cascade.detectMultiScale( frame_gray, faces, 1.1, 2, 0|CV_HAAR_SCALE_IMAGE, Size(30, 30) );

  for( size_t i = 0; i < faces.size(); i++ )
  {
    Point center( faces[i].x + faces[i].width*0.5, faces[i].y + faces[i].height*0.5 );
    ellipse( frame, center, Size( faces[i].width*0.5, faces[i].height*0.5), 0, 0, 360, Scalar( 255, 0, 255 ), 4, 8, 0 );
```

And after this, put `cout << faces[i].size << endl;`

The complete code can be found [here](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/objdetect/cascade_classifier/cascade_classifier.html). Read more about Haar Feature-based Cascade Classifier for Object Detection [here](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/objdetect/doc/cascade_classification.html).